# Order by in KQL

Tags: sharepoint

How can I make a Order by date in KQL in SharePoint?

```
 ((IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") AND SFSNewsDateOWSDATE:"2014") Order by date
```

I know the Order by part is wrong, but what is correct?

Comment: Are you talking about Sharepoint's Keyword Query Language? If so, [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938031.aspx) discusses sorting, in general, in Sharepoint and links off to how to do it in KQL. If not, please elaborate on what KQL means to you, because it's not clear from this question as it stands.

Comment: Yes it is in SharePoint. I take a look at your link.

Comment: ((IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") AND SFSNewsDateOWSDATE:"2014") | Order by date